# if statement condition changing style of element?

Tags: javascript, css, input

I have the following Javascript which intends to conduct a `function`, if an `input` has `border-color: red;` as seen below:

```
if (input.style.borderColor = "red") {
  input.onkeydown = function () {
    input.style.borderColor = "black";
  };
};
```

What happens though, is the `if` condition `(input.style.borderColor = "red")` actually changes the `border-color` to red, and I'm unsure why it is doing so.

If anyone knows why this is occuring I'm grateful to know why. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because inside your if statement its not checking to see if its red its assigning it to red. One `=` character assigns the value and two (or three) `==` or `===` checks it. So your code should be this:

```
if (input.style.borderColor === "red") {
  input.onkeydown = function () {
    input.style.borderColor = "black";
  };
};
```